# sas page footnote in ods pdf

Tags: pdf, sas, sas-ods

I'd like to have a page number in the format of "X OF Y PAGES" at the right bottom of each page. 
I tried the following code for a pdf result but it's just displaying "Page *{thispage} of &num" literally. Can anyone help with this? Thanks!

```
* create the file with the number of pages */

ods results;

ods pdf file="c:\temp\pagenumb.pdf" compress=0;

footnote j=r "Page *{thispage} of &num";

%pdf_code;

ods pdf close;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close in your attempt. I'll do it like this:

For example:

```
options nodate nonumber;
data work.animals;
    input name $ weight;
    datalines;
    monkey 20
    shark 500
    lion 200
    wolf 120
    buffalo 400
    ;
run;

ods pdf file = 'C:\sasdata\animals.pdf';
ods escapechar= '!';
proc print data=work.animals;
    title 'Animals';
    footnote j = r 'Page !{thispage} of !{lastpage}';
run;
ods pdf close;
ods listing;
```

Basically I chose to use an exclamation mark "!" for my escape character as a way to grab SAS's attention. Then we can use a foot note with right justification since we want it on the bottom right hand side (`j = r`). We can also use `j = l or c or r` depending on which side you want the footnote to be on.

And finally I used `ods listing` because I don't want to view the output in SAS (I only want to output a pdf file). Cheers.